# SwiftUI Charts - Have circle at intersection of a LineMark and RuleMark?

Tags: swiftui, charts, linemark, rulemark

I have a vertical slider that moves left to right intersecting the orange and red curves. Is it possible to put a small circle at the intersection of the rule and the curves?

[image]

This is the type of code I'd use but RuleMark has no idea where the intersection point is. Is there a command in SwiftUI which can accommodate this?

```
           RuleMark(x: .value("Date", datesArray[Int(daySlider)].sunrise))
                .foregroundStyle(Color.black)
                .lineStyle(StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 1))
                .symbol() {
                    Circle()
                        .fill(.orange)
                        .frame(width: 10)
                 }
```

Comment: you could recycle my answer to this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75222361/swiftui-charts-linemark-symbol-touch-event/75230158#75230158  , to find the location of the intersection, and display a `Circle/Symbol`

Comment: If there is no inbuilt command I'll follow your post - thank you.